# Restrict Image size (<1MB) upon HTML5 canvas resize

Tags: html, canvas, image-resizing

I have a HTML5 uploader for images. I upload two images for any image that the user selected. One is 64x64 and the other is 320x240. 
I am using `canvas.drawImage()` to resize the images. Everything is working fine.

However,How can i ensure that the images after resize-ing is <= 1MB . Does the size of image after resize depends on the browser being used?

Comment: Assuming your image is 24-bit, Uncompressed image file size can be calculated as follow: `320px x 240px x 24bit = 1,843,200 bits = 230,400 bytes`. It shouldn't exceed 1MB. ([Calculator](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/lrm22/pixels2bytes/calculator.htm))

Comment: how do i get the image color depth?screen.colorDepth gives me the depth of colorPalette.Will it be same for the images displayed in the screen?

Comment: Yes. FYI, RGB is 24-bit. 99% you're using RGB.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor canvas is actually 32-bits, RGB + alpha channel. Only for JPEG will the result be 24-bit, for PNG it will be 32-bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot guarantee the size as the resulting compressed file is dependent on the content for how well it will be compressed.

If you have an image with high frequency (many details, noise etc.) then it will be harder to compress and you need to use a stronger quality setting (for JPEG) to filter away more data.

You can however calculate the raw size of the image. Canvas is 32-bits, that is three 8-bits channels for RGB (24-bit) + one 8-bit channel for alpha.

If you save your images as PNG you will have RGBA - the size for that is:

```
width * height * 4 = size in bytes
```

If you save out as JPEG you will have only RGB:

```
width * height * 3 = size in bytes
```

JPEG can be heavier compressed than PNG so you can reduce the size more by using the optional quality parameter for `toDataURL(type [, quality= [0.0, 1.0]])`.

For your example size the *raw* size would be:

```
320 x 240 x 4 = 307 200 bytes (/ 1024 = 300 kb / 1024 = 0.29 mb).
```

and with RGB (no alpha)

```
320 x 240 x 3 = 230 400 bytes (/ 1024 = 225 kb / 1024 = 0.22 mb).
```

When an image is converted to a data-URI the content is encoded as base-64. Base-64 always add 33% to the size due to the way the data is being encoded (plus a small header to actually make it a data-uri, IIRC about 14-20 bytes).

In any case, you should be well within the 1 mb limit in this case.